# How to smooth the edges after importing an SVG?

Tags: modeling, vertices, import, edges, svg

I have imported an SVG file to create a shape from it, selected 2D, and added bevel on my item.

The problem is I get sharp edges which I am not able to get rid of, I need a nice round look.

Any suggestions?[image: SVG with bevel added with 2D shape selected]

Answer (score 0):

It won't create an entirely curved top surface, but if you want just to get rid of the sharp transition from the (by default circular) 'Round' Bevel, you could use a custom profile instead:

[image]

Not the greatest interface, but I've found the easiest way to make the transition smooth is to set both fixed control-points in the corners to 'Free', and add one more point in the middle of the curve, 'Automatic'.

Working under a sensitive matcap, you can make coarse adjustments to the position of the automatic point by dragging the point itself, and then you can make fine adjustments by shift-dragging in the X and Y number fields. Likewise for the lengths of the free handles on the corner-points.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried that, works close but still can see the edges, is there any way of exploding flat svgs to a round mesh?

Comment: @SanketS  Do you mean like [this](https://imgur.com/a/sr5iOLq)? ... (that's a _Screw_ modifier)

Comment: yes, exactly like that, a 360 fill. but it's coming with its own problems for me

it shows lines running around the object, however, I need it to be smooth. 
Please see the screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emXRdQ1XAYB0G-4SuvrNSX8cAi869ze4/view?usp=sharing)

I tried sub divide but it didnt do the trick :/

Comment: @SanketS  can you show us the topo / share the file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, Sure, here is the file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=8VjkdloX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/8VjkdloX/)

Comment: Hi @SanketS ! I've made a commentary [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139453/panda-smooth), because otherwise this would get too long. Please find an adjustment made according to that rationale [here](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zpDGYOXr/)

Comment: Hi @Robin, thank you so much for the detailed explanations, it is very detailed, I am new to using shapes in blender so it is very useful for me.